# Meaning of removing first digit from a binary number?

Tags: binary

If you have a binary number say 1010 (which is 10 in base 10), is saying that dividing by two will remove the first digit (making it end up as 010), true?

Basically how do you remove the first digit (i.e. if the binary number is 0 or 1, then it will end up as nothing)? I don't want code or anything, I just want to know like something like you divide or multiply by two.

Also do not consider any of the left most zeroes, of a binary number.

Comment: Division by 2 will remove the least significant digit, or the first digit counting from right to left. Can be achieved easily by right shift `>>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works the same way as it does in base ten. The number 401, without its first digit, is 1. You've subtracted 400, no? Now, to divide by ten, you would SHIFT the digits to the right. 401 shifted right is 040. 401/10 = 40. Note that the 1 is discarded because we're working with integer division.

So in binary, it's exactly the same, but with powers of 2. Removing the first bit does not DIVIDE by two. It SUBTRACTS the value of its position. So 101b (which is 4+1 = 5), without its largest bit, is 001b, or 1 decimal. It's subtraction: 5 - 4 = 1.

To divide by two, you shift the bits to the right, just like in base 10. So 101b would become 010b, which is 2 decimal. 5/2 == 2 (we're dropping the fractional part since it's integer division)

Make sense? If you're ever confused about binary, just think of how the digits & positions work in base ten, and instead of powers of ten, use powers of two.

Answer (score 1):

If by "first digit" you mean "first significant digit", then what you're looking for is something like `number and not (1 shl (int(log number / log 2)))`, where `and` and `not` are the bitwise operations, `shl` means shift left, and `int` is rounding down (never up) to integer. `log` is just a logarithm, in any base (same base for both cases).

If by "first digit" you mean the digit in some nth position (let the rightmost position be 0, counting to the left), then you just do `number and not (1 shl position)`.

Answer (score -1):

Removing a digit is like changing it to 0.  Changing 1010 to 0010 is accomplished by subtracting 1000:  1010 - 1000 = 0010.

Comment: It is not always obvious that you need to subtract 1000 from 1010 to get 10. How do you know it is 1000, and not 10000 or 100? aaaaaa123456789's answer address this problem.